# External Code Sources Homework

Tags: python, time, while-loop, return

I've been writing my computer science homework on external code sources that times how long it takes someone to guess a question.

However when I run it I receive this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/Documents/Guess band member.py", line 14, in <module>
    start = time.time()
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'time'
```

I would be very grateful if someone could help me resolve this.

```
import time
print("You can type 'quit' to exit")
Exit = False

Band = ["harry", "niall", "liam", "louis" ]

while Exit == False:
    print("Guess a band member")
    start = time.time()
    Guess = input(":")
    end = time.time()
    Guess = Guess.lower()
    if Guess == 'quit':
        Exit = True
    elif Guess in Band:
        print("You're right")
    elif Guess == "zayn":
        print("Wrong")
        print("He left.")
    else:
        print("Fool!")
    time = end - start
    print("You took", time, "seconds to guess.")
```

Comment: `time = end - start`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You replaced the `time` module you imported at the top with a floating point value here:

```
time = end - start
```

In the next iteration of your `while` loop, `time` is now a `float` object, and not the module object, so your `time.time()` call fails.

Rename that variable to something that doesn't clash:

```
elapsed_time = end - start
print("You took", elapsed_time, "seconds to guess.")
```

As a side note, you don't need to use a sentinel variable (`Exit`); just use `while True:` and exit the loop with a `break` statement:

```
while True:
    # ...

    if Guess == 'quit':
        break

    # ...
```

In other circumstances, you'd use `while not Exit:` rather than test for `== False`.